# Showing % discount on product collection page

Tags: products

I'm trying to display %age discount on product collection page, following these tutorials:
http://www.pauldonnelly.net/magento-display-sale-icon-if-special-price/
http://shamimcse05.wordpress.com/2010/12/23/get-special-price-or-regular-price-in-magento/

I've declared these in the above code:

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
```

Then i've used this loop to get all the products:

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
```

Under this loop, i'm trying to add these lines, I've tried following the above mentioned tutorials as it is, but they starting giving errors, so i mixed, them up to get rid of errors, and here is what the code has become:

```
         <?php $specialprice = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSpecialPrice();
            $thisProduct= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(product_id); 
            $regularprice = $thisProduct->getPrice();
            // Get the Special Price FROM date
            $specialPriceFromDate = $thisProduct->getSpecialFromDate();
            // Get the Special Price TO date
            $specialPriceToDate = $thisProduct->getSpecialToDate();
            // Get Current date
            $today = time();
            if ($specialprice):
                if($today >= strtotime( $specialPriceFromDate) && $today = strtotime( $specialPriceFromDate) && is_null($specialPriceToDate)):
                    $discount = (($regularprice-$specialprice)/$regularprice)*100 ;
                endif;
            endif; ?>
```

I'm using the code below to check output:

```
                echo "Discount is: ".$discount = (($regularprice-$specialprice)/$regularprice)*100 ."% OFF" ;
                echo "</br>Special Price is: ".$specialprice;
                echo "</br>Regular Price is: ".$regularprice;
                echo "</br>Special Price from date is: ".$specialPriceFromDate;
```

and this is the output on the page for the products, which have been assigned special price, with valid start and end dates:

```
Discount is: 0% OFF
Special Price is: 500.0000
Regular Price is:
Special Price from date is:
```

It is getting the values of Special Price, but it is not reading the regular price value,'From Data' and 'To Date'.

Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$myproductobject = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
$specialprice = $myproductobject->getSpecialPrice();
$regularprice = $myproductobject->getPrice();
$specialPriceFromDate = $myproductobject->getSpecialFromDate();
$specialPriceToDate = $myproductobject->getSpecialToDate();
$today = time();
if ($specialprice):
    if($today >= strtotime( $specialPriceFromDate) && $today <= strtotime($specialPriceToDate) || $today >= strtotime( $specialPriceFromDate) && is_null($specialPriceToDate)):
        $discount = (($regularprice-$specialprice)/$regularprice)*100 ;
    endif;
endif;
```

Comment: Depending on your collection you can also try to delete line 1 and replace $myproductobject with already loaded $_product. Saves you one product model load.

Comment: There seems to be a problem in the if statement, it isn't letting code let thru:
 if($today >= strtotime( $specialPriceFromDate) && $today = strtotime( $specialPriceFromDate) && is_null($specialPriceToDate)):

     endif;

Comment: try edited version

Comment: The original code wasn't able to run due to a typo here : `$thisProduct= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(product_id); `  product_id is not a variable.